# Only implement support for a subset of types that implement a trait

Tags: generics, rust

Sometimes in Rust, types implementing a trait depend on platform specifc behavior such that it's not possible to deal with them entirely generally through only the trait interface. In this case, it would be useful to implement general code once, and platform specific code on each concrete type.

For example:

```rust
trait IncompleteInterface {}

struct PlatformA;
struct PlatformB;

impl IncompleteInterface for PlatformA {}
impl IncompleteInterface for PlatformB {}

impl PlatformA {
    fn baz() {}
}

impl PlatformB {
    fn fizz() {}
    fn buzz() {}
}

struct PlatformDependent<T: IncompleteInterface>(T);

impl<T /* Constrain to PlatformA and PlatformB */> PlatformDependent<T> {
    fn foo() {
        Self::bar();
    }
}

impl PlatformDependent<PlatformA> {
    fn bar(&self) {
        self.0.baz();
    }
}

impl PlatformDependent<PlatformB> {
    fn bar(&self) {
        self.0.fizz();
        self.0.buzz();
    }
}
```

Without a constraint, this can't compile, because the compiler can't be sure there is an appropriate implementation for `PlatformDependent::baz()`. For instance if, someone implements `impl IncompleteInterface for PlatformC {}`, then obviously `PlatformDependent<C>(platformC).bar()` won't work.

Is there a way to tell the compiler the general implementation only works with Platforms A and B?

Comment: @Shepmaster Unfortunately, this isn't a duplicate. See the update to my question.

Comment: The question you asked, "Constrain generic to specific set of types", has been answered by the duplicates. The answer is "no", along with a whole bunch of alternatives. [Creating a trait works fine here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a71e161254efb8f0b5ee0f6ca5f3ab0)

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, you playground link pushed me in the right direction. If you're curious, [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c7859de2eea4d3b04cf5c86f9e4ced78) is what I tried that made me think traits wouldn't work, and [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=12940a3c0f7ddb73d4c0773f02dac753) is what worked to constrain the implementation to a specific subset of Foo.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm going to rewrite this question, since the actual question asked was answered by the two linked questions, but the underlying problem was different. I'm also going to write an answer using your playground code under the assumption you don't mind. If that's not the case, I can delete the answer.